# Concatenate multiple chars

Tags: c++, file, char, concatenation

I m reading a file and I would like to extract all of its contents and store them into a single char in C++. I know it can be done with strings however I cannot use strings and need to resort to char instead. I can I concatenate multiple chars to one char variable?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
 string str = "";
 ifstream file("c:/path.....");
 while (file.good())         
{
    str += file.get();       
}   
const char* content = str.c_str();
printf("%c", *content);
```

but this just gave me the first letter of the file and that's it.

If also tried:

```
 ifstream file("c:/path.....");
 char c = ' ';
 char result[100];
 while (file.good())         
{
    c= file.get();  
            strcat(result,c);     
}
```

but this gave me runtime errors all the time.

Comment: Are you talking about a char array?

Comment: I just edited my post describing what I've tried.

Comment: In general, files are too big to fit into a single character.  If the space allocated to a `char` type on your platform can accommodate a single file, more power to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second try you gave in your question (which I guess from your other hints, is what you finally want), you can try the following as a ***quick fix***:

```
 ifstream file("c:/path.....");
 char c[2] = { 0, 0 };
 char result[100] = { 0 };
 for (int i = 0; file && (i < 99); ++i)         
 {
     c[0] = file.get();  
     strcat(result,c);     
 }
```

Since using `strcat()` might not be very efficient for this use case, I think a better implementation would directly write to the `result` buffer:

```
 ifstream file("c:/path.....");
 char result[100] = { 0 };
 for (int i = 0; file && (i < 99); ++i)         
 {
     result[i] = file.get();  
 }
```

Comment: strcat looks like overkill in this situation, is not it ?

Comment: Ohh, missed that note

Answer (score 1):

In your first code block:

```
const char* content = str.c_str();
printf("%c", *content);
```

prints only the first character of the string because `*contents` dereferences the
pointer to the (first character of) the string, and `%c` is the printf-format for
a single character. You should replace that by

```
printf("%s", content);
```

to print the entire string. Or just use

```
std::cout << str;
```

Comment: OK I didn't know that it dereferences the pointer to the first character of the string. OK but say I don't want to print it out rather just store it (like I said preferably in a char variable), how can I do this?

Comment: @Morelka: A `char` variable holds a single character. Do you mean a `char` array?

Comment: @Morelka: Then there are working solutions in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that :

```
 char result[100];
 int i = 0;

 while (file.good())         
 {
    c= file.get();  
    if(i<100)
       result[i++]=c;
 }

  result[i]='\0';
```

There a lot of things to improve in this solution (what would you do if there more then 99 chars in your file, file.good() not the best option for loop condition, and so on...). Also it is much better to use strings.I don't know exactly why you can't use them, but just in case you change your mind you can read your file like that :

```
std::string line;
while ( getline(stream, line)) {
  process(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `std::string`s of your characters and concatenate them:

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'b';
std::string concatted = std::string(1, c1) + std::string(1, c2);
```

This works because of the fill `std::string` constructor, see [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Comment: From the OP's question: _'... however I cannot use strings ...'_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To me it is somewhat unclear what this is referring to. I suppose it is referring to the *inputs*. In my example, `c1` and `c2` are not strings.

Comment: I read it, the OP can't use `std::string`s (which might be more likely than he/she can't use `char[]`, `char*`) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not even sure which strings he is referring to, `std::string`, c-style strings `char*` or even some strange library-specific strings? Or `std::wstring`?

Comment: Yes I mean I cannot use std::string however I could use char*.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously, you are new to the c++ or at least you're using some strange terminology.

First of all, I advice you to read some c++ literature for beginners (you can find list of it on stackoverflow). Then you will understand all the conceptions of strings in c++.

Second, use this code to read file content and store it in a char*.

```
FILE *f = fopen("path to file", "r");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *content = new char[fsize + 1];
fread(content, fsize, 1, f);
fclose(f);

content[fsize] = 0;

cout << "{" << content <<"}";

delete content;
```

Comment: The OP said he can't use strings... Not sure if your answer really answers the question, however I'm not really sure what the OP is referring to exactly.

Comment: The OP's asking for single `char` values, not `char[]` arrays!

Comment: I guess that 'strings' mean 'std::string'.Otherwise the question is meaningless because there is no such opportunity to store a file content in a single char, lol.

Comment: Trying to modify a string literal won't go down too well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've tried this but cannot use strings ie std::string.